# Copy Library/List in SharePoint 2013 2 gig

Tags: 2013, library, content-migration

I have a library/list that is roughly 2 gigs.  I need to copy it and place the new copy under a different name in the same SharePoint 2013 site.  I am trying to retain the historical data and column information from library/list A to library/list B and allow for additional columns and information to be added to the new list without affecting the original library/list A.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell you can export the list and import it in new location. This will retain your history and versions.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx

Comment: PowerShell, Microsoft product?

Comment: It's a language for scripting. You can execute it using SharePoint Management Shell

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Export-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) and [Import-SPWeb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx) commands to export and import a library/list. They would basically export the data onto file system, and then import it back into SharePoint to the URL you designate. (And of course) Version history can be retained if you require.

The syntax would be similar to below:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity <SiteURL> -Path <Path and File Name> [-ItemUrl <URL of Site, List, or Library>] [-IncludeUserSecurity] [-IncludeVersions] [-NoFileCompression] [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]
```

However I should warn you that I have faced a lot of difficulty initially to get the Urls right. Here's an article to help you with that: [Export-SPWeb Syntax Changes Between Root Site and Sub Sites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/briangre/2014/03/18/export-spweb-syntax-changes-between-root-site-and-sub-sites/)